# Which DTD would make the first XML document valid and the second invalid?

Tags: xml, dtd, sgml

I'm looking for a DTD which would make the first XML document valid and the second invalid, if it's possible.

First XML:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <D>bla</D>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
    </B>
</A>
```

Second XML:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <C>bla</C>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <D>bla</D>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
        <C>bla</C>
        <D>bla</D>
    </B>
</A>
```

I've got this one, but it does not exclude the second:

```
<!DOCTYPE A [
<!ELEMENT A (B+)>
<!ELEMENT B (C|D)+>
<!ELEMENT C (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT D (#PCDATA)>
]}
```

Comment: Maybe `<!ELEMENT B ((C,D)+,D*)>`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to accomplish semantically.  Often, thinking in terms of the application domain - rather than completely opaque As Bs and Cs - clarifies requirements.  Here, one can only guess at the *real* pattern to be captured.  For instance, this would answer your question, but would it address what you really need?

```
<!ELEMENT A (B+)>
<!ELEMENT B (C,D+)+>
<!ELEMENT C (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT D (#PCDATA)>
```